# removing "()" using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove "()" from text file using python.

My input line looks like this:

```
 N1B N 1.2620(4) 0.3320(4) 0.0049(7)
```

I want:

```
N 1.2620 0.3320 0.0049
```

Basically do not want any number that is wrapped by parentheses, and want to discard the first column.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would suggest giving the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) a try.

Comment: have you tried anything at all? if so, what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regular expressions with `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'N1B N 1.2620(4) 0.3320(4) 0.0049(7)'
>>> re.sub('\(.*?\)', '', s)
'N1B N 1.2620 0.3320 0.0049'
```

`?` sign is for making you regex *lazy*. Without it you'll get:

```
>>> re.sub('\(.*\)', '', s)
'N1B N 1.2620'
```

If you want to delete *only* digits, use `\d` insted of `.`:

```
>>> s = 'N1B N 1.2620(spam) 0.3320(4) 0.0049(7)'
>>> re.sub('\(\d*?\)', '', s)
'N1B N 1.2620(spam) 0.3320 0.0049'
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but I wanted to also get rid of the first column for output.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, without using a lazy quantifier, you can use

```
re.sub('\([^)]*\)', '', s)
```

Also, to remove the first column, just use

```
re.sub('^[^ ]+ ', '', s)
```